# If I have a function does basically the same thing as another, what would be the best way to join them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, refactoring, code-reuse

I have a function that displays a "board" of a battleships game. Then another function that displays the same board but hides spots that have boats in it (as to not give them away to the user). The code is:

```
def display(self):

       os.system("cls")
       print("Displaying {} grid \n".format(self.name)) 

       i = 0 #this block prints column numbers
       print("O", end="  ")
       for h in range(1,10+1):
           print(h,end="   ")
       print("\n")

       while i < 10: #this block prints row letters and board
           print(chr(i+65), end= "  ")
           row = self.board[i]
           for j in row:
               print(j, end="   ")
           i += 1
           print("\n") 


   def hide (self):
       os.system("cls")
       print("Displaying {} grid \n".format(self.name)) 

       i = 0 #this block prints column numbers
       print("O", end="  ")
       for h in range(1,10+1):
           print(h,end="   ")
       print("\n")

       while i < 10: #this block prints row letters and board
           print(chr(i+65), end= "  ")
           row = self.board[i]
           for j in row:
               if j == self.aboathere:
                   print(self.noboat, end="   ")   
               else:
                   print(j, end="   ")
           i += 1
           print("\n")
```

There is a tiny difference, the if structure below "for j in row" in hide, but its basically the same function. It works fine but seems kinda redundant. How can this be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution might be adding a switch argument to your function which will show/hide the boats:

```
def show_board(self, show_boats=False):
    os.system("cls")
    print("Displaying {} grid \n".format(self.name))

    i = 0  # this block prints column numbers
    print("O", end="  ")
    for h in range(1, 10 + 1):
        print(h, end="   ")
    print("\n")

    while i < 10:  # this block prints row letters and board
        print(chr(i + 65), end="  ")
        row = self.board[i]
        for j in row:
            if j == self.aboathere:
                print(j if show_boats else self.noboat, end="   ")
            else:
                print(j, end="   ")
                
        i += 1
        print("\n")
```